# Xcode doesn't list iCloud documents

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

My iOS app is storing documents in iCloud, and yet Xcode's "iCloud Report" says iCloud is disabled and doesn't list any documents.

iCloud seems to work correctly, but I'd like to be able to use Xcode to debug file transfers. Once upon a time, Xcode showed the iCloud documents.

Here is the report:

[image: iCloud Usage]

And here is the list of iCloud documents from the device:

[image: iCloud documents]

Perhaps the source of this issue is that I'm sharing a single ubiquity container between iOS and Mac versions of my app (for document sharing). However, I've changed the container to "Use Default Container" and the problem persists. Also, the documents do show up in the Mac version.

Please let me know what additional information you may need.

Possibly related: [iCloud Documents not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295176/icloud-documents-not-visible)

Comment: Did you ever figure out why Xcode shows iCloud disabled on the device?  I have the same issue.