# How to upload file to iCloud Drive?

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-api, icloud-drive

In My app I want to upload PDF files to iCloud drive which use can access from URL https://www.icloud.com/#iclouddrive .

I have try mane code like

- https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/12779/icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-1

but non of the above help me to upload file to iCloud Drive. Above all example is used to sync files between two device through the app. But I want to upload to Drive so the user can access them with out the app also. I want to implement this form App.

Comment: Did you used the search function?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300094/swift-write-save-move-a-document-file-to-icloud-drive