# Swift - Can't connect to iCloud documents

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, icloud-documents

I am trying to use iCloud documents to store backup files from an iOS app (Xcode 11.3 and Swift 5).

I set up the base of the iCloud capability but I can't get an URL for the container.

Here is the iCloud capability setup
[image]

The entitlements file
[image]

The key added in the Info.plist

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
    <dict>
        <key>iCloud.com.alienfamily.TestiCloudAgain</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
            <string>myCloudTest</string>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
            <string>Any</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

The code I tried

```
let iCloudDocumentsURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")

if iCloudDocumentsURL != nil {
    print("All good")
} else {
    print("I'm sad")
}
```

I follow many tutorials (like this one [tutorial](https://theswiftdev.com/how-to-use-icloud-drive-documents/) ) and check other posts ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295176/icloud-documents-not-visible/30079516#30079516)) without any results.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was pretty simple, it was to test it on my iPhone who have an account correctly setup and not on the simulator.